# Lua concurrency in multi thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, lua, server

If I want implement a server which only has two functions which are login and signup, how can I achieve best concurrency performance?

Here is some methods that I can thought.

1st, if there is only one thread, the answer is quite clear. Only Lua's `coroutine` can be used for this purpose.

2nd, if I have a multi-core cpu, and I want to take advantage of this, multi-thread would be taken into consideration. In this scenario, if I use **only one lua_state and also implement lua_lock**, and using Lua in a thread-safe mode, but I think that will cause a serious lock overhead problem. Because, I found Lua calls lua_lock most everywhere. One optimal method that I can thought is that I **use multi lua_states(created by lua_new thread, share global tables) for each thread and not implement lua_lock**, but I think this only works for read-only operation(login). What about signup, shall I just lock the global table when signing up?

I think the final answer would be multi-thread + lua.coroutine(creating 1 thread per core, and using coroutine in each thread). But I don't no how.

Comment: Short answer: You MUST implement `lua_lock` (yes, it will cause lock-waiting almost everywhere).  Lua is not good for multi thread environment.  Another solution is to use separate Lua VMs (created by `luaL_newstate`) with externally implemented sharing of data (through serialization or copying), for example, look at "Lua Lanes".

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to take a deep looking at Lua Lanes.@EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: If you don't like what you find & do it manually, a thing that you could do (if you only need occasional access to shared data) is to have one Lua state as a "data store" and one Lua state per thread. Threads work on their own and to get/set shared data, you lock the data store thread, get/set the value, then unlock it. (Don't rely on `lua_lock`, you want less fine-grained locking for that – across the whole set or get, not its sub-steps. Look at [`lua_getextraspace`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_getextraspace) for space to store the lock.)

Comment: "have one Lua state as a "data store" ", that's a nice hint for me. Thanks.@nobody

Comment: @nobody - Is it safe for two Lua threads in the same Lua VM to work in two parallel CPU threads without accessing "shared data"?  Can these threads simultaneously read from global environment `_G`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I don't mean "sub-states"/coroutines created via `lua_newthread`, I mean completely independent states. (While you might get multiple Lua threads of the same state to work in parallel, that would likely involve lots of locking.)

Comment: @nobody - I didn't understand how do you suggest to access "shared data" located at "data store" Lua state from other Lua threads?  How to access data from different Lua VM?  "Completely independent states" means "different Lua VMs", isn't it?

Comment: I think multi threads using sub-states created by 'lua_newthread' to read simultaneously shared data from origin lua_state is safe(without any writing operation). Right?@nobody

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, different VM. Which has the standard Lua C API, so you can set single values (or also structs as lightuserdata, or flat tables via for loop copy) somewhere in a forest of tables or get & return them. Just pack the lock/traverse/(get|set)/cleanup/unlock sequence up as get/set functions which you push as Lua C functions into the worker states. The workers can then use the independent state to store shared data. (To the workers, the storage state looks essentially like a library, and it's locked only during accesses.) (Is that clearer now?)

Comment: @nobody - OK, you are emulating shared data in worker states by issuing C API commands to "data store" VM.  But how to pass arbitrary Lua value from "data store" VM stack to worker VM stack?  Will you emulate all shared Lua values as userdata to be able to intercept all operations on them?  For example, when Lua code at worker state says `local x = shared.a.b.c.d` will you create 4 userdata in worker VM?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff How do you read something like `shared.a.b.c.d` into "you can [get or] set single values [via] get/set functions"? I'm saying that `val = get( {key,...} )` / `set( {key,...}, [old,] new )` with `key[i]`/`val`/`old`/`new` being "simple values" (bool/number/string/light udata) or `val`/`old`/`new` optionally being a flat table of only simple values is probably enough for most uses. (Exposing volatile structure seems like a bad idea: Another thread sets `shared.a = nil`, what happens (& when)?) (If you want stuff like that, use a more complex library.)

Comment: @francis Any allocation (incl. string/table/… creation, stack resize for function call, …) & some other stuff as well (setting a metatable with `__gc` field, …) will mess with the GC structures which are shared between threads/coroutines of the same state. If you can guarantee that no one ever does any of those things there *may* be a very small set of operations that are safe to do in parallel (and may change from (even minor!) Lua version to version), but if even one thread does one of these things none of the others may run or things will likely explode. (I wouldn't try it.)

Comment: @nobody - If you are only limited by nonvolatile flat tables of simple values, then why do you need "data store" Lua thread?  Just store these simple values in C objects without creating "data store" VM.  Yes, you should implement "associative array indexed by strings/numbers/booleans" somehow in your C code to emulate shared flat Lua table.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The only efficient way to use OS threads in Lua is to create individual Lua states for each thread. You can implement it by yourself or take some exist solution, e.g. https://github.com/effil/effil.